# jQuery .click event

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery. I'm playing with a menu that slide when the user click on the arrow.
I used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.userArrow').click(function(){
$('#dropdown-1').slideToggle(300);
});//end click
});//end ready


<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown-menu has-tip">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#1">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#4">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#5">Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#5">Item 6</a></li>
    </ul>

           </div>
        <a id="name_header">
<span class="pic">
  <?php echo $link?>
</span>
<?php echo ''.$user_data['first_name'];?>
<img class="userArrow"  width="7" height="5" alt="" src="images/arrow.png">
</a>
```

It works only when I click twice. Is there any other events that works clicking just once?
thanks

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the HTML as well?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code sample, you are not closing your opening div for dropdown-1. This could be the root of the issue. Your jQuery looks fine.

Comment: No probs. Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 1):

As Fraser said, your code looks fine apart from the unclosed `div`.

[This is probably what you want just with a button instead](http://jsfiddle.net/BTdVn/1/).

Comment: thanks for the example. it was not what I was trying to do but you definitely have my upvote. cheers

Comment: @mattia Glad you fixed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I change the code and now works with just one click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.userArrow').toggle(function(){
$('#dropdown-1').slideToggle(300);
 },function(){
 $('#dropdown-1').hide();
 }
 );//end toggle
 });//end ready
```

thanks to everybody!